# Simple undirected graphs question

Tags: graph-theory

Let G = (V, E) be a simple undirected graph of n vertices. There is one vertex of degree $n-1$. 
How many simple undirected graphs we can form such that the graph contains only one vertex of degree n−1

It is straight forward but I am stuck. Any hint would help. Thanks.

**Simple: No loops, no parallel edges. Undirected: it isn't a digraph

Comment: Are these graphs labeled?  Is the vertex of degree $n-1$ a specifically labeled vertex that we know the label of ahead of time?  Or is the star graph where vertex $1$ is the center of the star counted as a different graph than the one where the vertex labeled $2$ is the center of the star?

Comment: No, any vertex can be that particular vertex.

Comment: Assuming vertex $1$ is the vertex of degree $n-1$ and no other vertex may be of degree $n-1$, notice that there are $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$ ways to fill out the rest of the edges if we didn't care about if there were any other degree $n-1$ vertices, seen by noting there are $\binom{n-1}{2}$ available positions for as of yet undecided edges, each of which may either be included or not included in the final graph.  Several of these arrangements will be bad where there were additional degree $n-1$ vertices.  Get rid of these and correct the count using inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Simple: No loops, no parallel edges. Undirected: it isn't a digraph, is this what you mean by these 2 terms? Also is your question "How many simple undirected graphs we can form such that the graph contains only one vertex of degree $n-1$"? If not please clarify the question.

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: @JMoravitz Say there are 5 vertices. There are 290 graphs contain only one vertex of degree n−1?

Comment: I got a count of $220$, not $290$.  You had requested a hint rather than a full solution.  If you wish for me to share my calculation, I will.

Comment: I got 220 now. Thank you.